# C/C++ floating point issue

Tags: c++, c, floating-point

I am struggling with a basic floating-point precision issue.  Here is the problem:

```
double d = 0.1;
d += 0.1;
d += 0.1;

d == 0.3 ? std::cout << "yes" : std::cout << "no";
```

Run the code and you get "no"

I understand that C/C++ store values in binary and that binary storage can not exactly store every value.  I also understand that these small errors compound as you do various math operations on them (i.e. d += 0.1;).

My questions is if I do need to test if d == 0.3 (to a reasonable precision.. as is the clear intent of code above)... how do I do that?  I hope the answer is not:

```
if (d > 0.2999 && d < 0.3001) ...
```

ALSO.. this works

```
float f = 0.1;
f += 0.1;
f += 0.1;

f == 0.3f ? std::cout << "yes" : std::cout << "no";
```

but I can find no equivalent "0.3d" in the language.

Thanks

Comment: Here we go again... Read this: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: because it is not precise. search floating point representation

Comment: Check the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/) or the [SO C FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c?sort=frequent&pagesize=50).

Answer (score 3):

One common way of testing equality to a certain "tolerance level" is using [`fabs`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fabs.html):

```
if (fabs(d - 0.3) < 1E-8) {
     ...
}
```

Comment: From skimming cppreference.com it appears there are `float` and `double` overloads of `std::abs`, and I can't imagine a reason why there shouldn't be. Only **C** `abs` is integer-specific. So why use `fabs`?

Comment: @delnan Because the question is tagged as C and C++ :)

Comment: Didn't notice, thanks. But as OP is using C++ code in the question, I'm assuming that the C tag has little significance.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to compare the difference between `d` and `0.3f` with a very small number.

You may try:

```
 float epsilon = 1e-5;
 if (fabs(d - 0.3f) < epsilon)
 {
     std::cout << "yes" ;
 }
 else{
     std::cout << "no " ;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`0.3f` is a `float` literal. If you want a `double` literal, you have to use `0.3` (without suffix), as `double` is the default. `0.3l` would be a `long double`.

Comment: Are we seeing the same question? (Perhaps it was edited.) The `0.3f` is used in the second snippet, where f is a `float`. There is no `0.3l` in the question.

Comment: @delnan: I answered this part of the question (seeing how `std::abs()` / `fabs()` was already covered by others): *"...but I can find no equivalent "0.3d" in the language."*

Comment: I misread the part about `0.3l` (the explanation that `0.3` is a double made sense), and as a consequence misread the intent of your answer. Never mind.